# Android: Fragment is too slow at loading

Tags: android, performance, user-interface, networking, fragment

I'm trying to solve this problem for weeks now but I can't solve it so I really hope to find help here.

I'm creating an app which is working much with the webserver so there are many queries to do. In my Fragment, named "tab_profile" I call 2 queries to the API and many other to load images on my custom ListView.

So my problem is that this fragment needs 1-2 second on loading (well connection) and even crashing on bad connection e.g. 3G.

The code is somehow looking like this (Short version of course):

```
public class tab_profile extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
private String imagepath = null;
private ImageView imageview = null;
View rootView = null;
private ArrayList<PollItem> arrayPolls;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_profile, container, false);

    final Button button_follower    = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_follower);
    final Button button_following   = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_following);
    final TextView text_username    = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text_username);
    imageview                       = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.img_own_pp);
    final Session session           = new Session(getActivity());
    final Network network           = new Network(getActivity());

    text_username.setText(session.getValue("username"));
    if(session.getValue("username").length() < 3) {
        getActivity().finish();
        return null;
    }

    JSONArray arr;
    String res = network.POST("{\"token\":\"" + session.getValue("token") + "\"}", "profile.php");
    try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(res);
        arr = obj.getJSONArray("data");

        if (!obj.get("status").equals("false")) {

            button_follower.setText("Follower\n" + arr.getJSONObject(0).getString("follower"));
            button_following.setText("Following\n" + arr.getJSONObject(0).getString("following"));

            if (arr.getJSONObject(0).getString("pp").equals("true")) {
                network.setImageViewImage(imageview, "usermedia/pp/" + session.getValue("id"));
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    arrayPolls = new ArrayList<>();
    getList();

    //listeners here

    return rootView;
}
```

Then the second main function which is called "getList()":

```
    public void getList() {
    Network netwok = new Network(getActivity());
    Session session = new Session(getActivity());

    String resp = netwok.POST("{\"token\":\""+session.getValue("token")+"\","+
            "\"get\":\"true\""+"}","mypoll.php");

    try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(resp);
        JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("data");

        if(obj.get("status").equals("false")) {
            return;
        }

        arrayPolls.clear();

        for(int i=0; i<arr.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject ot = arr.getJSONObject(i);
            PollItem tmp = new PollItem(ot.getInt("ID"),ot.getInt("userid"),
                    ot.getString("description"),ot.getString("username"));
            arrayPolls.add(tmp);
        }
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ListView list_poll_item = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_friend_poll);
    PollOverviewItemAdapter adapter = new PollOverviewItemAdapter(getActivity(), arrayPolls, tab_profile.this, imageview);
    list_poll_item.setAdapter(adapter);
    list_poll_item.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
```

And my queries are sent by this Async. function:

```
    private class POST_REQUEST extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String line;
        try {  
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(params[0]);

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters;
            postParameters = new ArrayList<>();

            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json", query));

            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            line = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            line = "<results status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server</msg></results>";
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            line = "<results status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server</msg></results>";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            line = "<results status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server</msg></results>";
        }
        return line;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

and the last function:

```
    public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
      ImageView bmImage;

      public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
          this.bmImage = bmImage;
      }

      protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
          String urldisplay = urls[0];
          Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
          try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
          } catch (Exception e) {
              Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          return mIcon11;
      }
      protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
          bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
      }
}
```

So I think those were the important parts of my code. I really hope to find a solution for this problem. And I've tried many times to load first my UI and then later the data from server but it was the same. I tried this by using "onStart()".

Thanks in advance... :-)

Comment: "even crashing on bad connection e.g. 3G" -> Can you post the crash log for this?

Comment: Hey @TrevorCarothers, it's only on my mobile device not on my virtual machine.

Comment: That's probably b/c your VM uses your computer's internet. Please post that crash log.

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to do this on my phone but I think I know the problem: My App is loading everything before showing the userinterface so if the connection is slow it needs too long and it crashes. So I think that's my problem: I have to load data in background.

Comment: You just need to look at the output of logcat when your app crashes to see the crash log. But yeah, my guess is that network.POST("{\"token\":\"" + session.getValue("token") + "\"}", "profile.php"); within onCreateView() is taking a long time.

Comment: If I add them to the async function it stucks... and doesnt crash, very weird...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found my own solution. I just used my asnyc function wrong. If I do everything in onPostExecute() the app works well. Before, I did the main part in doinbackground callback so it somehow got stuck.